# How to validate option buttons in option group if no selection made access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In access form I have a option group contains two radio buttons. I'm trying to validate option group, if any of the radio button is not selected then I need to give message to user that please select any option. Here name of the option group is **grpfiletype**. It is not working.

How do I check null selection in the option group.

```
If (Me.grpfiletype= Null) Then
    MsgBox "Please select filetype "
    Exit Sub
    Me.grpfiletype.SetFocus
End if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If IsNull(Me.grpfiletype) Then
```